# How to load an HTML5 Canvas with an image from an image-service?

Tags: javascript, canvas, angular5

My web app calls a Web API service, which returns an image. The service returns nothing but an image. Calling the service is little different because there is a function in the routing code that adds the required auth-code and such. Anyway, my point is, I don't have the full URL and even if I did, I wouldn't want to pass it into code in plain-text. So what I have is a response, and that response is an image.

```
    getThumb(filename: string) {
        return this.http.get('/Picture/' + filename).subscribe(response => {
            return response;
        });
  }
```

What I need to do is draw that image on to a canvas. From what I've seen on the internet so far, it looks like I want to create an image element, then assign that element src a URL, then I can add it to the canvas. It's the src part that's perplexing me. All the samples I see are either loading the image from a local filesystem or predefined URL, or from a base64 string, etc. I can't figure out how to just load an image I have as a response from a service. I'm sure I'm overthinking it.

Does anyone have some sample code to illustrate this?

e.g Something like this:

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.src = ... ; // Set source to image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the image to Base64. In my example, you request the image and convert it to a blob using `response.blob()`. Once it's a blob, use `fileReader.readAsDataURL` to get the Base64.

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fetch("image-resource").then((response) => {
    if(response.ok) {
        return response.blob();
    }
}).then((blob) => { 
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    fileReader.onloadend = () => {
        console.log(fileReader.result);
    }
});
```

References:

- [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL/)
- [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: Updated example to use onloadend instead of `then()` because the results was hit and miss.